# PHP echo formatting of html

Tags: php, echo, string-formatting

I am trying to echo out multiple table rows on my sql query and provide them with alternating colors to improve the aesthetic value of my site.  I am fairly new to php and I am extremely fussy over the presentation of my code and therefore I would like to include the output html into my PHP block to improve readability.

I have browsed some past threads but I am still rather unclear of how the formatting of a string works in PHP, the code below shows my attempt of formatting the output:

```
echo '<tr class=" . 'if( $class_style %2 == 0 ){ echo "row_dark"; } else echo "row_light"' . ">';
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Regards
Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like this right syntax:

```
echo '<tr class="'.($class_style %2 == 0 ? "row_dark" : "row_light").'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an `if structure` in an `echo`.
Use that :

```
echo '<tr class="'. ($class_style %2 == 0) ? 'row_dark' : 'row_light' . '">';
```

It's a ternary operation.

Comment: Thank-you for your response, greatly appreciated - this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`echo '<tr class=" '.` instead of `echo '<tr class=" .'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<tr class="'.(($class_style %2 == 0)?'row_dark':'row_light').'">';?>
```

or

```
<?='<tr class="'.(($class_style %2 == 0)?'row_dark':'row_light').'">';?>
```